# heroku pg:psql got error `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

when I tried to do `heroku pg:psql --remote origin`

```
C:\Sites\allmain\actest>heroku pg:psql --remote origin
Your version of git is 1.9.4.. Which has serious security vulnerabilities.
More information here: https://blog.heroku.com/archives/2014/12/23/update_your_git_clients_on_windows_and_os_x
---> Connecting to DATABASE_URL
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require': cannot load such file -- dl/import (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:121:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/pageant.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent/socket.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/agent.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/key_manager.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh/authentication/session.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-2.9.2/lib/net/ssh.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/net-ssh-gateway-1.2.0/lib/net/ssh/gateway.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:69:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/heroku-3.43.5/lib/heroku/helpers/heroku_postgresql.rb:54:in `maybe_tunnel'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/heroku-3.43.5/lib/heroku/command/pg.rb:149:in `psql'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/heroku-3.43.5/lib/heroku/command.rb:212:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/heroku-3.43.5/lib/heroku/cli.rb:34:in `start'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/heroku-3.43.5/bin/heroku:24:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/heroku:23:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/bin/heroku:23:in `<main>'
```

I am using

```
Windows 7

heroku-gem/3.43.5 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.2.4
heroku-cli/5.2.30-bb2a990 (windows-386) go1.6.2
```

Comment: did you tried heroku run bash?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Heroku installs and depends on ruby 2.1.7, but for `pg:psql` it uses a ruby.exe in your path, which in my case is 2.3. I temporarily added a reference to 2.1 and it worked.

The only workaround I found is to pass the db url to psql directly (powershell):

```
psql (heroku config:get DATABASE_URL)
```

I also suggest you to keep git updated, simplest using chocolatey: `choco install git`, `choco outdated` to see new versions, `choco upgrade` to install them.